# Why is the resolution of screen in Android NDK wrong?

Tags: android-ndk, resolution

I get the resolutions like that:

```
    // ... other standard includes ...
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>

//...

struct fb_var_screeninfo fb_var;
int fd = open("/dev/graphics/fb0", O_RDONLY);
ioctl(fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &fb_var);
close(fd);
// screen size will be in fb_var.xres and fb_var.yres
```

It is correct when the screen does not have home, back and menu button.

[image]

But it is wrong with those 3 buttons.

Comment: What were you expecting? You are querying the low-level framebuffer device, it knows nothing of software buttons.